# Javascript ToDo List (localStorage)

Tags: javascript

I am really new to coding and am struggling with implementing localStorage. I have to make a todo list that allows the user to input items to create a list. Whatever list is made has to be saved to localStorage so that when the page refreshes, the todos on the page stay there. It also has to keep the status of whether the words have been struck through with a line or not. I have tried googling solutions and can't seem to find what I am looking for to understand how to make this work.

Everything else works well except the localStorage.

I appreciate any assistance! Thanks!

Javascript:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#add-item');
    const input = document.querySelector('#first-item');
    const itemList = document.querySelector('#item-list');
    
    itemList.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if(e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON'){
           e.target.parentElement.remove();
        }
    });
    
itemList.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName === 'LI'){
        if(e.target.style.textDecoration === "line-through") {
         e.target.style.textDecoration = "none";
        } else {
            e.target.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
        }
    }
    
});


form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(input.value);
    const newItem = document.createElement('li');
    const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
    removeBtn.innerText = 'Remove';
    newItem.innerText = input.value;
    newItem.appendChild(removeBtn);
    itemList.appendChild(newItem);
    input.value = '';

    let localStorageItem = {name:"newItem", status:""}
    localStorage.setItem("localStorageItem", JSON.stringify(localStorageItem));
    let storeItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localStorageItem"));
});
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ToDoApp</title>
    <link rel ="document" href="4.4 TODO App Exercise.js">

</head>

<body>

<h1>ToDo List</h1>

<form action="" id="add-item">
    <label for="first-item">First Item</label>
    <input type="text" id="first-item">
    <button>Add to List</button>
</form>

<ul id="item-list">

</ul>

<script src="4.4 TODO App Exercise.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you know, that the localStorage doesn't work correctly? At the moment, all you do is save the data and get the data again, in the submit handler. You don't even log the gotten data. Does `console.log(storeItem)` output the saved data? If so, localStorage works.

Comment: is it a list you want to store it the local storage , because it looks like you are just storing an object with only one key-value pair?

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your answer. It seems that with my code, what is entered into localStorage when I put an item onto the list is : {"name":"newItem","status":""}. I entered 'item 1' so I thought that what would be saved into localStorage would be 'item 1'. Also, currently when I refresh the page, everything resets and it's gone. I am supposed to make it so that the todo items entered stay on the page after a refresh of the page. I am sorry if I am overcomplicating it. I started coding 2 months ago and I know this is supposed to be simple, but the struggle has been real.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ToDoApp</title>
    <link rel ="document" href="4.4 TODO App Exercise.js">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>ToDo List</h1>

<form action="" id="add-item">
    <label for="first-item">First Item</label>
    <input type="text" id="first-item">
    <button>Add to List</button>
</form>

<ul id="item-list">

</ul>

<script src="4.4 TODO App Exercise.js"></script>

</body>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  
    var names = [];
var oldNames=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("names"));;
    if(oldNames!=null && oldNames!=''){
for (let i = 0; i < oldNames.length; i++) {

      const newItem = document.createElement('li');
    const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
    removeBtn.innerText = 'Remove';
    newItem.innerText = oldNames[i];
    newItem.appendChild(removeBtn);
    itemList.appendChild(newItem);
}
}else{

}
    

});
const form = document.querySelector('#add-item');
    const input = document.querySelector('#first-item');
    const itemList = document.querySelector('#item-list');
    
    itemList.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if(e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON'){
           e.target.parentElement.remove();
        }
    });
    
itemList.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName === 'LI'){
        if(e.target.style.textDecoration === "line-through") {
         e.target.style.textDecoration = "none";
        } else {
            e.target.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
        }
    }
    
});


form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(input.value);
    const newItem = document.createElement('li');
    const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
    removeBtn.innerText = 'Remove';
    newItem.innerText = input.value;
    newItem.appendChild(removeBtn);
    itemList.appendChild(newItem);
     //  let storeItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localStorageItem"));
var names = [];
var oldNames=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("names"));;
if(oldNames!=null && oldNames!=''){
names=oldNames;
names[oldNames.length] =  input.value;
localStorage.setItem("names", JSON.stringify(names));
}else{
names[0] =  input.value;
localStorage.setItem("names", JSON.stringify(names));
}

     input.value = '';
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You can add code for clear local storage